# How to calculate the probability of percentage?

Tags: probability

I want to calculate the probability of choosing 7 damaged items out of 35% total damaged items, is it correct if I calculate the probability of choosing 1 out of 35% and then multiply the result by itself seven times?

Comment: Yes, if you choose 7 items in total and the amount of items is suffiently large. How large is your population ?

Comment: In fact, I just get a percentage, I don't know the actual number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is assumed that the population is large enough. Let $D$ be the number of defective items and $N$ the number of defective and non-defective items. In this case the probability of picking $7$ defective items (without replacement) is

$$P(X=7)=\underbrace{\frac{D}{N}}_{\frac{D}N}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{D-1}{N-1}}_{\approx\frac{D}N}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{D-2}{N-2}}_{\approx\frac{D}N}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{D-3}{N-3}}_{\approx\frac{D}N}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{D-4}{N-4}}_{\approx\frac{D}N}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{D-5}{N-5}}_{\approx\frac{D}N}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{D-6}{N-6}}_{\approx\frac{D}N}$$

In your case $\frac{D}{N}=35\%$. If $D$ and $N$ are sufficently large enough then the probability of picking an defective item at the i-th pick can be approximated by   $\frac{D}{N}$.

Comment: I see, if D and N are sufficiently large, then the answer is approximately 1/n * 1/n * 1/n ..... etc.

Comment: No, it is approximately $\frac{\color{\blue}{D}}{N}\cdot\frac{\color{\blue}{D}}{N}\cdot\frac{\color{\blue}{D}}{N}\cdot\frac{\color{\blue}{D}}{N}\cdot ...=\left( \frac{\color{\blue}{D}}{N}\right)^n$ for a sample size of $n$

Comment: Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: @user3779823 You´re welcome